# Conditionally assigning a table column to a property in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and was wondering if there was a way to conditionally map a property. For example, if column a has a value of 0, use column b as the value, else default to a.

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
@Column(name="ColumnA" > 0 ? "ColumnA" : "ColumnB")
private Integer myValue;
```

If anybody could help steer me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're working on Spring, you're probably importing the Hibernate implementation, so this is a good usecase for the `@Formula` annotation ([documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html)).

> Defines a formula (derived value) which is a SQL fragment that acts as
>   a @Column alternative in most cases.

The `@Formula` annotation accepts native `SQL`, so for this kind of logic, a `SWITCH`, or maybe the `SQL` function `COALESCE`, is what you should use.

Example:

```
@Formula("case when ColumnA > 0 then ColumnA else ColumnB end")
private Integer myValue;
```

Comment: @JamesWagstaff remember it accepts native SQL, so it's DBMS dependant.